# Syntax for creating a wait loop in cmd

Tags: windows, bash, cmd

I want to check if a file exists every minute in cmd. Could someone help with the syntax please?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following batch file should work:

```
@echo off
:loop
if exist FILENAME (
    echo "found"
) else (
    timeout /t 60 /nobreak > nul
    goto loop
)
```

Don't forget to replace FILENAME properly.